# Rigorous procedure followed by shape keys to merge models

Tags: shape-keys, shrinkwrap

Good evening, I would like to know how the Blender shape keys realize the merging of two 3D models after the shrinkwrap modifier has been applied. What is the algorithm exploited? Does it use interpolation? Are there refernces?

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by "rigorous"? Shape key is linear interpolation... but what is the question: how to merge two meshes (from same object) as shape keys?

Comment: I don't understand how the vertices move from one position to the other, but maybe with your answer it is more clear. After I use the shrinkwrap modifier the mesh topology of the two models become the same. For this reason, by changing the "value" setting, thanks to linear interpolation, the vertices are displaced from the positions they have on the basis key to the one on the target key. Is it right?

Comment: So... you want to apply the modifier as shape key, that's it? Yes the vertices are linearly displaced from the basis to the shape key.

Comment: I can use the modifier ahah. My problem was to understand the theory behind it!!!

Comment: I've written that the shrinkwrap modifier does not change the topology of the "shrinked" model, but it just projects all the vertices on the target surface. In this situation I've not a 1-to-1 correspondance of the vertices. This is the reason why I don't understand the linear interpolation that Shape Keys realize

Comment: And I don't understand what you mean by shape keys here, except if you're talking about applying the modifier as shape keys. Shrinkwrap in itself is not a shape key. So your question is about how shrinkwrap works? Or?

Comment: I've used the shrinkwrap modifier, than I have applied it as shape key. Now , going in Object Data Properties, I' m modifyng the Shape Key Value obtaining the morphing from one model to the other. I hope that in this way it is more clear. I just want to understand what is the logic the software used to move the vertices.... I thought the topology was the same, but it is not like this

Comment: ok, this is clear now. Thanks. I confirm that changing the shape key value is simply linear, but per vertex/for each individual vertex (not for the whole mesh in itself). Maybe provide an example in your question if something is more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take an example. A plane projected onto some steps using shrinkwrap modifier:

[image]

We apply as shape keys.

And now, here is how the plane moves for several values for the shape key:

[image]

As you can see, this is linear.

If a vertex goes from X when shape key is 0 to Y when 1, then its position is:

```
X + <shape key value> * (Y - X)
```

Note that we take here shrinkwrap example, but shape keys go the same whatever the way they are produced from.